# Print $name value in php

Tags: php, html

I am trying to print out the value of `$name`

yet it keeps printing out `$name` instead of the value here is the line:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="$name"');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP will only evaluate variables within double-quoted strings, not single quoted strings like you've used in your example.

Try this instead (if you need to output double quotes within a double-quoted string, you need to escape them with a backslash, otherwise PHP will treat them as the end-of-string delimiter):

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$name\"");
```

Comment: ORIGNINAL: header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="HELLO"');

Comment: i am trying to make it so there is a variable where hello is but the filename command needs double quotes

Comment: @Matthew what it was printed is another question. You should ask "How to perform a manual download" instead of this silly syntax question.

Comment: +1 for explaining the difference between single and double quotes

Answer (score 2):

String interpolation does not happen between single quotes.

```
$name = "test";
echo "Value: $name"; // Value: test
echo 'Value: $name'; // Value: $name
```

More details [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what your looking for

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$name.'"');
```

This would give a header like so:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="some_file_name.ext"
```

Hope this helps

Another way to do this is using `sprintf`

```
$header = sprintf('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="%s"',$name);
header($header);
```

The `sprintf` is not really needed but there to show you how the variable would be placed into the header string

Comment: I do this practically every day, I assure you my methods are correct, more than likely your variable is null or incorrect. Please show more code, Also if it was you who down voted me, can you please restrain from down voting answers that answer your question, if the answer did not work i assure you its another section of your code.

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with `single-quoted` strings, always concatenate variables.

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $name . '"');
```

Comment: but filename needs double quotes and needs another one at the end

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$name);
```

Comment: this will break if $name contains spaces, hence why his original code had it wrapped in double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use `"` instead of `'` like :

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$name);
```

Comment: You got an extra `'` at before the closing parenthesis.